# Strange problem on some client's browsers

Tags: php, encoding, https

We are fighting a strange problem on the company that I work.

We created a site of a promotion to a client where its consumers can register products barcodes to win prizes. The site was created using PHP and MySQL. The site uses SSL on every form.

However, some consumers report to the client's call-center they was no able make a registration at the site.

We try everything, but we cannot, by no ways, reproduce  the problem. The consumers reported the problem on several browsers ranging from IE8 to Firefox, the problem is same on everyone them.

One co-woker this weekend was able to catch this same bug on his wife's notebook and brought her computer to the company so we could test. However, here on the company the problem didn't happened and we can make the registration normally.

We suppose this problem could be a matter of encoding and special characteres like ã and ç. But we are sure that all source files are UTF8- with BOM. We also suspect of MSXml version, but we are note sure anymore.

Because of legal impediments the client cannot ask the consumers to install anything on they computers to test or fix the problem.

Sorry but by complience rules we also cannot share the url of the site, what is a pity. I know it is too much on vacuun, but perhaps you could had crossed something similar.

Thank you

Comment: Could you at least describe what the issue was? "Some consumers not able to make a registration at the site" could cover a lot of cases! Was there an error message? If so, what was it? Is there anything in your server logs?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to be more specific.
There is a form the user is asked to fill out him/her personal information. The form is full of javascript animations and validation. On the submit event of the form we do an AJAX call to a php page that connects to a JBOSS webservice which register the user. On any error with the imputed data the corresponding input field is highlighted with a message informing the user. However, the users got the generic message when the web service failed to register and no field is highlighted. We think on encoding problems between the AJAX call and the web service.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information its going to be tough to answer this one, unless someone has specifically run into the problem before. Since you can't duplicate the error yourself, try capturing all of the exceptions that are uncaught in your application and report them (have them emailed to yourself, logged to a file, etc).

Use: `<?php set_exception_handler("customCatchFunction");` grab the backtrace, get var dumps on your session, post, get, server and start compiling enough information to be able to pinpoint the problem. When you're running a user-oriented application its always good to have a global exception handler to catch odd things that slip through the cracks of your try/catches (although it is not a replacement for proper try/catching and other error checking!).

Answer (score 0):

> One co-woker this weekend was able to catch this same bug on his wife's notebook and brought her computer to the company so we could test. However, here on the company the problem didn't happened and we can make the registration normally.

This definitely tells you it's not a problem of browser nor of hardware. One other thing I can think of is the Internet connection. Check if the customers are using specific firewall/network configuration that can (for whatever reason) interfere with your site.

Notably, I remember people having problems to see the old version of my website if they had Norton Internet Security on.

Comment: Norton Internet Security blocks HTTP_REFERER which I guess was your issue?

Comment: Haha, Norton is a virus in itself, I can definitely see it screwing with everything...

Comment: @Martin Smith: Yes, I think it was something like that (it was a few years ago, I decided to forget the details :D)

The worst thing was that it was bloody difficult to track out why they had an error!

Comment: It was indeed the most bizarre thing of the problem. We are asking for our IT right now for virtual machines and external modems to try other networks configurations.
We also we check for possibles anti-virus.

Comment: Highly improable that a firewall could allow some content through and deny some via SSL.

Comment: @symcbean: higly improbable but absolutely possible. As I was saying users were not able to see part of the content of my site when using Norton Internet Security. I cannot say that is the problem Gustavo has, but it can be. Furthermore, see the sentence I quoted. It must be something on the client network, do you see any other explanation for that?

Answer (score 0):

The information you've provided leaves a lot to be desired in terms of identifying what has happenned here. No error message? No indication of what the user experience was? No indication of how it failed? No indication of what you found when you went looking in the logs? Indeed, no details of any investigation?

Assuming you really have exhausted every avenue to identify the problem, then I'd suggest building a watchdog in javascript to monitor what's actually going on and phone home with a diagnostic when it identifies a failure. This will be a lot simpler if you can re-engineer your registration process around ajax calls.

> But we are sure that all source files are UTF8- with BOM.

eh? If your PHP code is UTF-8 with BOM, then you'll have all sorts of problems - PHP should be **ASCII*. If you mean user submitted data, then why do you need users to upload a file in a such a poorly specified format to register?

HTH

C.

Comment: I really sorry but I can't really share nothing directly. It is the rule of the client. We have no exhausted everyting to correct it yet. However we trying almost everything to try to reproduce it, with no success. It is a very very specific problem. I know it is really difficult to have any ideia of is happening with such shallow information i had provided. However we got a start with possibles softwares ans network configuration and we gonna re-force the log to register the exact SOAP.
About the UTF, sorry it is WITHOUT bom, I typed wrong. We used it because of the used php framework.